# Determine Default EC2 m3.xlarge MaxRequestWorkers setting

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4

One of my client apps is experiencing a great deal of traffic, and we're accordingly attempting to tune the EC2 m3.xlarge server farm. We're currently seeing the following error:

```
[Thu May 18 20:01:15.387630 2017] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2723] 
AH00161: server reached MaxRequest Workers setting, consider 
raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
```

Logically I want to raise this setting, however we have searched high and low and cannot determine the default value. We don't want to get carried away and increase it to much lest we introduce other problems. Therefore we're trying to establish a baseline. However, the MaxRequestWorkers setting appears to be compiled into `mod_mpm_prefork.so`. None of the Apache-related commands (`httpd -v`, etc.) seem to be capable of listing all compiled settings. I've even tried using `strings` and `xxd` to view the binary, but can't find the specific setting.

I'm at wits' end. Any input very much appreciated.

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with AWS support, and they confirmed everything I concluded in the original question, and confirmed MaxRequestWorkers is unchanged from that found in a stock Apache installation (256).

Answer (score 0):

The default is listed in the [Apache Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers):

> For non-threaded servers (i.e., prefork), MaxRequestWorkers translates
>   into the maximum number of child processes that will be launched to
>   serve requests. The default value is 256; to increase it, you must
>   also raise ServerLimit.

Comment: I certainly understand this is Apache's default. But I'm referring to the default as set in the Amazon Linux AMI. The AWS documentation identifying these defaults is nowhere to be found.